# CSS3 fade-in effect in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css

for my navigation, I'm using a CSS fade-in effect for the sub navigation, but it only works in Chrome, not in Firefox.

```
.mega .hover ul.level-2 li:nth-child(5n+1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
  }

  .mega .hover ul.level-2 li:nth-child(5n+2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
  }

  .mega .hover ul.level-2 li:nth-child(5n+3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
    animation-delay: 0.55s;
  }

  .mega .hover ul.level-2 li:nth-child(5n+4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
    animation-delay: 0.65s;
  }
```

Here is the example:http://jsfiddle.net/rzf7w69u/28/

Thanks for you help.

Comment: have you tried it with *-moz-* prefix? e.g. *-moz-animation-delay*

Comment: From the fiddle, I see the same in Chrome and Firefox. Please include an [MCVE] that clearly demonstrates the issue. (ps: unprefixed version of animation-delay is supported by all major browsers since 2016~17

Comment: I compiled the SCSS again and now its working, very strange. BY THE WAY how can I mage the navigation to open by click?

Answer (score 0):

Use prefix for Firefox and Opera

```
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
 -o-animation-delay: 0.4s;
```